# Firebase authentication for a PHP site

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, firebase

This is my last attempt to figure this out before giving completely up.
And sorry for the complete novice approach.

I have built a site, written in PHP, and no database. It has an admin backend.
In the admin there is only one index file, that includes all the other necessary files and stuff. So in this index there is a small javascript script that checks the user auth state in firebase. If the user is not authenticated it will go to a login.php and handle the authentication, firebase style.

The problem is, that my php code can't possibly know, if the firebase user is authenticated or not; thus everything on the admin page is generated regardless the auth state, and then hidden or redirected by javascript. (I know).

So my question is. How can I outsource the login process to firebase, and keep my site secure at the same time?

The complete source code is here, if you want to see anything:
https://github.com/soosgyul/QDP---Quick-Deploy-Package

Comment: normall your site's users will have absolutely no account on the DB. you use a standard account for the php<->db connection that's completely independent of the users.

Comment: yes. Users would have no accounts. And this is why I wanted to use firebase, so the site admin needs an account in the firebase app, and that's all the database the site needs.

Comment: giving users db-level privileges is a scary concept. however unlikely it might be, if they can get at your DB server via something OTHER than your code/interface, they can completely hose your site

Comment: what do you mean, giving db level privileges. There are no db level privileges, nor db.

Comment: normally you'd have the user provide a user/pass to your site, and then it's a simple (but way more complicated in reality) `select * from users where username=$user and password=$password`-type thing. if you get a record back, then the user's authenticated themselves. you don't need to give the user a DB-level account for that, just php so it can talk to the DB and issue that query. and that php account would be the SAME account for all users of your site.

Comment: http://www.gyulasoos.com/qdp/ look at this. Authentication is done with javascript... through firebase....